Can't access private variable from class .h in class .cpp C++
I am trying to access a variable in my class that is declared in the class .h file in the same class's .cpp file, though I keep getting this error:

a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

class .h:
#include <string>

#ifndef MAGIC8BALL_H
#define MAGIC8BALL_H

class Magic8Ball {
    const std::string responses[20] = {"It is certain", "It is decidedly so", 
        "Without a doubt", "Yes definitely", "You may rely on it", 
        "As I see it, yes", "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes", 
        "Signs point to yes", "Reply hazy, try again", 
        "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", 
        "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", 
        "Don’t count on it", "My reply is no", "My sources say no",
        "Outlook not so good", "Very doubtful"};
public:
    Magic8Ball();
    static void response();
};

#endif

class .cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

#include "../include/magic8ball.h"

using namespace std;

Magic8Ball::Magic8Ball() {
    srand(time(0));
};

void Magic8Ball::response() {
    int index = rand() % 20;
    cout << responses[index] << endl;
}

The error is in the Magic8Ball::response() function at the last line when accessing responses[].
I tried changing the responses[] to a vector of strings, and an array of char*, neither worked. Also, I tried declaring all of the responses in responses[] in the class constructor, but I'm getting the same error because the constructor is in the .cpp class file.

Given that the error is mentioning "static", do you know what the static in your program is doing?

response is a static method, and so it cannot access non-static members like responses (since it does not have a this, i.e. current object). You can make responses static.

The title does not match the error message.

Unrelated note: put the include statements inside the include guard so you don't have to re-include them if the including header is included twice. Saves a bit of time compiling.

Side note: srand has global effect. Because Magic8Ball::Magic8Ball() reseeds the generator for everyone, every time you construct a new Magic8Ball, you reset everybody's number sequence. This can lead to interesting bugs. In general, you want to call srand only once, up near the start of main. If you find that's not sufficient, you should consider using more advance random number generation facilities like the Random library added to C++ in C++11

Side note: Avoid Magic numbers.  int index = rand() % 20; is vulnerable to change. if the number of elements in responses changes, index may have the wrong range of values and either miss a few elements or run off the end of the array. In C++17 or better use int index = rand() % std::size(responses); In older C++ use the clunkier and much less safe int index = rand() % (sizeof(responses)/sizeof(responses[0])); or write your own version of std::size (which, it turns out, is really easy).

Trying random type changes is not clear thinking.  Read and understand the error message, take appropriate action. In this case a static function cannot access a non-static member.  Const members are not implicitly static.  In this case you simply need a static const.  Although in this case I would suggest a static const char*[] rather than std::string[].

static void response(); why is this static?

Side note: you can replace all of this class stuff with a single free function.
